# python os.system seems to hang for no reason

Tags: python, ssh, os.system

So I am monitoring the modification time of numerous files. When the file is updated, I copy it over ssh to another machine. Here is a SSCCE of what I have:

```
import os
import time

send = "/home/pi/PythonScripts/tempData.txt"
check = "/home/pi/PythonScripts/check.txt"

statbuf = os.stat(send)
print "Modification time:",statbuf.st_mtime 

def wr2(data):
    file2 = open(check, 'w')
    file2.write(str(data))
    file2.close()
    return 0

def rd():
    file = open(send, 'r')
    line2 = file.readline()
    file.close()
    return line2

def rd2():
    file2 = open(check, 'r')
    line2 = file2.readline()
    file2.close()
    return line2


while(run):
   try:
    statbuf = os.stat(send)
    line2 = rd2()
    print line2

    if (str(statbuf.st_mtime) == line2):
       print "File has not changed...\n"
       time.sleep(1)
    else:
       data = rd()
       print "Data in File: " + data
       os.system("sudo scp /home/pix/PythonScripts/tempData.txt server1:/home/tix/Server1_SSH/Real_Data.txt")
       wr2(statbuf.st_mtime)
       print "New Modification Time:",statbuf.st_mtime 
       time.sleep(1)



   except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print '\nKeyboard Interrupt Caught!'
        run = 0
        raise
```

So when it gets to the `os.system()` command it hangs there not doing anything... however when I run the same exact code on the python interpreter it works just fine. I can't seem to understand what the issue would be... any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *sudo* is the likely culprit and is probably asking for a password.

Instead of *os.system*, try using the [*subprocess* module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) instead.  That will let you see the *stdout* and *stderr* streams to see what is going on.

Also, I would question the practice of using *sudo* inside your script.  Normally, the decision to use *sudo* would be left to the person calling the Python script.

Comment: I did think that too, however in the python interpreter it works just fine without any issues...

Comment: actually you're right, I removed the sudo and now it works perfectly. Thanks!